# Where is the actual code for interrupt service routine found in?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, microprocessors

I know that the ISR is found in the interrupt vector table , But where is the actual code for it found in , Is it in MSDOS.sys or IO.sys?

Comment: It's in RAM, pointed to by the IVT.  It has to stay loaded permanently, and can't be demand-paged in from disk because real mode doesn't have paging.  Presumably it's just loaded from a disk file sometime during DOS bootup, but I without knowing anything about different DOS implementations I wouldn't rule out there being runtime fixups to whatever's loaded.

Comment: I would imagine that different ISRs would reside in different files. If memory serves, msdos.sys would contain code for high-level interrupts (21h), and lower-level interrupts would be in io.sys. Loader would load those two files and place their contents in memory, and register interrupt routine with CPU.

Comment: In theory there can be 256 different ISRs registered at the same time. Which one do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Each interrupt has its own handler. Vector (which is just memory address in hex form 1234:5678) can point to:

1. BIOS which is read-only
2. any other .sys or program which has been loaded later after system boot-up
3. additionaly to 2 - when returning from custom handler it can call the original (previous) handler, what is common practice in MS-DOS